# Prototipo de aplicativo em python

Tags: python, app

Rapaziada, to com um trabalho da facul em criar um prototipo desses aplicativos de estacionamento, e sou meio novato em programação e gostaria de saber o que eu poderia melhorar nessas linhas de codigo:

```py
telaInicio = int(input("Digite 1 para se cadastrar ou 2 para entrar: "))


if telaInicio == 1:
    usuarioCadastro = input("Digite seu usuario: ")
    senhaCadastro = input("Digite sua senha: ")
    print("Cadastro efetuado com sucesso !")

if telaInicio == 2:
    usuarioLogin = input("Digite seu Usuario: ")
    senhaLogin = input("Digite sua Senha: ")
    print("Acesso Confirmado !!!")
print("Para a utilização do aplicativo é necessario ter creditos em sua conta")
valor1 = int(input("Digite 10 para 10R$, 20 para 20R$ ou 50 para 50R$ : "))

if valor1 == 10:
    print("Voce comprou 10 Reais em creditos")
    if valor1 == 20:
        print("Voce comprou 20 reais em creditos")
    if valor1 == 50:
        print("Voce comprou 50 reais em creditos")

#opcoes para o usuario escolher
print("Para compra de creditos digite 1: ")
print("Para definir horario, carro ou dia digite 2: ")
print("Para cadastrar o veiculo digite 3: ")
print("Para vizualizar seus creditos digite 4: ")
print("Para vizualizar o ultimo uso digite 5: ")

opcao = int(input("Digite sua Escolha: "))

if opcao == 1:
    valor1 = int(input("Digite 10 para 10R$, 20 para 20R$ ou 50 para 50R$: "))
    if valor1 == 10:
        print("Voce comprou 10 Reais em creditos")
    if valor1 == 20:
        print("Voce comprou 20 reais em creditos")
    elif valor1 == 50:
        print("Voce comprou 50 reais em creditos")


if opcao == 2:
    carroDia = int(input("Deseja definir seu carro digite 1, Para definir seu dia e horario digite 2: "))
    if carroDia == 1:
       carroDefinido = input("Qual carro deseja definir ?: ")
       print("O carro",carroDefinido,"foi definido com sucesso !")
    if carroDia == 2:
       diaHorario = input("Digite o dia e o horario que deseja definir: Ex: 19/05 as 17:00: isso ira custar 10R$: ")
       print("Seu dia e horario ficaram definidos para: ",diaHorario)
       print("Seu saldo ficou com: ",valor1 - 10)


#opcao para cadastrar veiculo
if opcao == 3:
     cadastroCarro = input("Digite o ano e o modelo do carro: Ex: Honda Civic 2013: ")
     cadastroPlaca = input("Digite a placa do seu veiculo: Ex QAM-2513: ")
     print("O seu veiculo", cadastroCarro, "com o emplacamento",cadastroPlaca, "foi cadastrado com sucesso")

if opcao == 4:
    print("Seus creditos são de:",valor1,"R$")
```

Comment: O problema maior dessa pergunta, no meu ver, é que não tem sequer uma definição do que o soft deveria fazer, além de revisar o código precisa de "engenharia reversa" pra saber o que ele faz, tampouco diz qual o aspecto da revisão esperada, ficou quase "baseada em opinião" além de ampla. Poderiam surgir infinitas respostas com códigos completamente diferentes e até incorretos da forma que está, pra piorar um pouco. [Edit] conforme sugerido no quadro acima resolvendo essas questões poderia eventualmente viabilizar reabertura da postagem.

Answer (score 5):

1. O algoritmo para cadastrar a senha está errado. Tem que pedir duas vezes a senha e confirmar se é a mesma, se não for tem que acusar erro.
2. O código não usa laços (loops), como o `while`. Não chegou a estudar ainda? Eles são necessários para retornar a certas etapas do código, como no caso da inserção de um valor que falhou por estar fora do intervalo esperado, por exemplo, até que o usuário preencha corretamente (como por exemplo a senha do ponto anterior).
3. Você repete código, por exemplo o de compra de crédito. Estude como dividir o código em funções, aí poderá chamá-las quando precisar que aquela mesma porção de código seja executada em diferentes lugares.
4. Essa linha aqui ao contrário do que você pensa não está mudando o valor de `valor1`, ele continua valendo o que era antes:

   `print("Seu saldo ficou com: ",valor1 - 10)`
5. Os nomes das variáveis não estão terrivelmente ruins, mas não custa recomendar para estudar como dar bons nomes a variáveis. O pior que achei foi essa `valor1`.

Assim numa olhada por cima foi isso que achei que pode melhorar.